# How to clone a git repository using SmartGit as ssh client on Linux?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, smartgit

Unable to find clear instructions, and other questions have Windows answers.

Under hosting provider I have toggled 'Use SSH instead of HTTPS to access repositories':
[gitlab smartgit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phTvQ.png)

And I have configured smartgit as SSH client: 
[smartgit ssh client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXtEi.png)

I have my ssh key in the right folder: `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_4096_gitlab`

When cloning smartgit still asks me for http authentication. So my questions are:

- How can I clone a private repository using SmartGit as a SSH client on linux?
- At what point is smartgit going to ask me what ssh key to use?
- Or what name should I give my ssh key so smartgit recognizes it?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the **Clone** wizard, **Repository** page before clicking **Next**

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I had to add the ssh:// version of the url, once I did, smartgit asked me for the SSH key location and everything works now.